# Pageview with animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Records are coming from server (dynamically).

[image]

How to make this type of functionality in iOS with paging with action (Button Click) and animation effects?

Is there any SDK is available or shall we need to customize the things?

Comment: [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) is the answer for you.

Comment: @iPhonic, Thank you. I also found "https://github.com/solomidSF/YRCoverFlowLayout".